# How can I properly do this?

Tags: ios, swift

I was expecting to put Bitcoin's value change (in an hour) so that if the percentage value of change is less than 0 then it would be written in red color. But if not, it would be on green. But I don't know how to convert a double to a float value in Swift in order to make the comparison.

And show the percentage change in a UILabel by using cocoapods.

```
func updateBitcoinData(json : JSON) {
    let bitcoinChange = json["changes"]["percent"]["hour"].double

    if Float(bitcoinPriceChange) < 0 {
        bitcoinPriceChange.text = "%\(String(describing: bitcoinChange))"
        bitcoinPriceChange.textColor = UIColor.red()
    } else {
        bitcoinPriceChange.text = "%\(String(describing: bitcoinChange))"
        bitcoinPriceChange.textColor = UIColor.green()
    }
}
```

> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'UILabel' conform to 'BinaryInteger'
>   Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIColor'

Comment: This looks like Swift 2 code. That is seriously out-of-date.

Comment: You maybe also want to check out the Codable protocol for making sure your json is in the correct format.. Still, converting a double to a float by applying `Float(...)` shouldn't be an issue. Are you sure that's what causes the error?

Comment: Did you mean to write `if Float(bitcoinChange) < 0 {`?

Comment: Yea, thank you, it works what you suggest me. And function as I expected.